# Hugo does not build without ‘-t’ parameter

Tags: github-pages, hugo, netlify

Currently I am using Hugo on GitHub Pages with ease but I have a few problems in which you could possibly help me to solve. Thanks in advance if you take your time to care a bit about my question, I highly appreciate that. I am trying to be as short as possible.

My short introductory page is located [here](https://bozsikarmand.github.io/Homepage/)

My blog (which needs fixes) is located [here](https://bozsikarmand.github.io/Blog/)

- Both sites are set up via the Hugo Quick Start, therefore I used the submodule way of getting the themes instead of cloning.
- Both sites are deployed into separate repositories. I have asked in other channels what would be the best and cleanest form of maintaining these sites, then some said, GitHub Project Pages is nice.
- To reach this feature, I have set publishDir to docs in both projects
- Set the master branch with /docs folder option at GitHub Pages in both cases.

The content of my introductory page loads fine while - by default - the CSS of my blog does not really want to load. (The browser wants to search it at the root - where nothing is located - instead of /Blog).

I have avoided the problem by building my Hugo site with `hugo -t blog` and it works fine, you can check on the link above.

When I tried to link this to Netlify, it did not work. Unfortunately, it did not build with the default version of Hugo they provide, but I was able to fix this with the creation of netlify.toml where I set 0.36 for Hugo’s version.

So after that at Netlify I had to provide a build command. There hugo should go, but it did not work. CSSs are not loaded. Unfortunately, providing hugo -t blog as build command did not help either.

### What I would like to acheive:

To be able to build my site without parameters just as in the other case. :)

### Repositories of the projects:

[Homepage](https://github.com/bozsikarmand/Homepage)

[Blog](https://github.com/bozsikarmand/Blog)

Thanks,
Armand

Comment: I work with Netlify tech support and these types of problems are a bit easier to debug in our helpdesk - feel free to reach out to support@netlify.com for a hand.  Since you weren't "building" on github pages - just deploying built content - you could probably do the same on Netlify if you commit your built pages from your local machine and let us deploy them without a build command at all.

Comment: Also, it is not clear if you are moving your site builds to Netlify and hosting there.

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` parameter instructs Hugo to use the specified theme. You can instruct Hugo to use the same theme via "theme" setting in your config file instead of the `-t` command line parameter.

Comment: Can you please include an example of how the theme setting should look in the config file?

Comment: @Robert In the example given by OP, `-t blog` is used. This same result is achieved by putting `theme = "blog"` in `config.toml`.

Comment: Thanks @nekr0z and welcome to Stackoverflow!